# change text from panel to other panel in a SplitterWindow wxpython

Tags: wxpython

how can I get this peace of code works I mean I try to change the text by clicking the button, and it gives me an error,, please help.
Thank you all in advance.

import wx

import wx.grid as gridlib

class RegularPanel(wx.Panel):

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    self.SetBackgroundColour("blue")

    button1 = wx.Button(self, label="change the text")

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnChange, id=button1.GetId())

def OnChange(self, event):

    value = str(self.text.GetLabel())

    value = "this works"

    self.text.SetLabel(str(value))
```

class OtherPanel(wx.Panel):

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    self.SetBackgroundColour("white")

    self.text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'try to change this text', (40, 60))
```

class GridPanel(wx.Panel):

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    self.grid = gridlib.Grid(self, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)

    self.grid.CreateGrid(20,8)

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND)

    self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    notebook = wx.Notebook(self)

    page = wx.SplitterWindow(notebook)

    notebook.AddPage(page, "Splitter")

    hSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(page)

    panelOne = OtherPanel(hSplitter)

    panelTwo = GridPanel(hSplitter)

    hSplitter.SplitVertically(panelOne, panelTwo)

    hSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

    panelThree = RegularPanel(page)

    page.SplitHorizontally(hSplitter, panelThree)

    page.SetSashGravity(0.5)

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)

    self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

```
def __init__(self):

    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Nested Splitters",
                      size=(800,600))
    panel = MainPanel(self)
    self.Show()
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
app = wx.App(False)

frame = MainFrame()

app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `RegularPanel` does not have a reference (i.e. does not know) to `self.text` as that was created and lives in `OtherPanel`.

There are a couple of approaches to make this work. The simplest in this case would be to just pass the `OtherPanel` instance to `RegularPanel` when you instantiate it. Then you can have a reference to the other panel and access its widgets.

Here is your code with that modification:

```
import wx

import wx.grid as gridlib

class RegularPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, other_panel):  # <-- New argument added

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        frame = wx.GetTopLevelParent(self) 
        self.other_panel = other_panel # <-- Create a reference to other panel
        self.SetBackgroundColour("blue")
        button1 = wx.Button(self, label="change the text")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnChange, id=button1.GetId())

    def OnChange(self, event):
        value = str(self.other_panel.text.GetLabel())  # <-- Use other panel to set text
        value = "this works"
        self.other_panel.text.SetLabel(str(value))


class OtherPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("white")
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'try to change this text', (40, 60))

class GridPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid = gridlib.Grid(self, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(20,8)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        notebook = wx.Notebook(self)
        page = wx.SplitterWindow(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(page, "Splitter")
        hSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(page)
        panelOne = OtherPanel(hSplitter)
        panelTwo = GridPanel(hSplitter)
        hSplitter.SplitVertically(panelOne, panelTwo)
        hSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)
        panelThree = RegularPanel(page, panelOne)  # <-- Pass in other panel reference
        page.SplitHorizontally(hSplitter, panelThree)
        page.SetSashGravity(0.5)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Nested Splitters",
                          size=(800,600))
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You could use `PubSub` to do this sort of thing too. If you are interested in that approach, you can check out the following links:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.pubsub.html
- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you so much .

Comment: sorry las question, what if I want to send the text to the grid for example self.grid.SetCellValue(0, 0, "Hello") with the same button

Comment: You could pass the `GridPanel` to the `RegularPanel` as well and do it that way if you want to follow the example I provided.